# Fluentd Elasticsearch target index

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, fluentd

I'm using [Fluentd](http://www.fluentd.org/) to transfer the data into Elasticsearch.

**td-agent.conf**

```
## ElasticSearch
<match es.**>
  type elasticsearch
  target_index_key @target_index  
  logstash_format true
  flush_interval 5s
</match>
```

**Elasticsearch index :**

```
"logstash-2016.02.24" : {
    "aliases" : { },
    "mappings" : {
      "fluentd" : {
        "dynamic" : "strict",
        "properties" : {
          "@timestamp" : {
            "type" : "date",
            "format" : "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
          },
          "dummy" : {
            "type" : "string"
          }

        }
      }
    },
```

**Transmit json data :**

```
$ curl -X POST -d 'json={"@target_index": "logstash-2016.02.24","dummy":"test"}' http://localhost:8888/es.test
```

It should write the data to the given index instead of that It creates new index - logstash-2016.02.25 and it will write data into that. I want to write data to the given index.

Here is the Fluentd elasticsearch github link :
https://github.com/uken/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch

Please correct me if I'm missing something.

Comment: I think you have a typo, `type elasticsearch` should read `@type elasticsearch`.

Comment: I'm using td-agent v2 on centOS, it's working properly without @.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this is old but actually I run into the same problem and solved by

```
logstash_format false
index_name fluentd
```

This create only `fluentd` as index.
From official fluentd tutorial https://docs.fluentd.org/output/elasticsearch

`logstash_format` (optional): With this option set true, Fluentd uses the conventional index name format `logstash-%Y.%m.%d` (default: false). This option supersedes the `index_name` option.

For clean up of old indices please consider using Curator: https://github.com/elastic/curator

I hope it helps someone.

Comment: Thanks, this little sliver of information was exactly what I needed to get unblocked.

Comment: Hi, I am still running into the same problem. When I change the index_name the new indices dont appear on Kibana but when I set it back to the default index logstash it appears. Any suggestions are welcomed!

Answer (score 3):

try this,
its due to **logstash_format true**, please enter your index name in below index_name field (default value is fluentd)

```
<match es.**>
@type elasticsearch
host localhost
port 9200
index_name <.....your_index_name_here.....>
type_name fluentd
flush_interval 5s
</match>
```

after run this, please check index created or not by load below url in your browser

http://localhost:9200/_plugin/head/

have a good luck

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tried to change the logstash_format to false, but I'm getting same issue., now it creates duplicate index type.

Comment: did you declare index_name?

Comment: Yes. in my case it's test_index

Comment: Does it always take index_name in lowercase? I tried giving it in uppercase but it converted index_name into lowercase values.

Answer (score 2):

Its because you set `logstash_format true`, so you have to set the `logstash_prefix`.

Apache httpd example:

```
  logstash_prefix fluentd.httpd # defaults to "logstash"
  logstash_prefix_separator _   # defaults to "-"
```